# SAS Macro Variable and file extensions

Tags: sas

I have the following code at the end of my code to export the SAS data to an Excel File.
The RepDate is set up as follows at the start of the code:

```
%let RepDate = &SYSDATE9;
```

The date works perfectly, however when I use the following code to export the data:

```
PROC EXPORT DATA=MYData         
OUTFILE="C:\Documents and settings\Documents\myFile &RepDate.XLS"     DBMS=EXCEL2000 REPLACE;
RUN;
```

The date is entered into the file name okay, but XLS is added to the file name. The dot for the file extension is missing and the file name becomes:

```
myFile02APR2012XLS
```

This is not what I expected, I expected the file name to be as follows:
    myFile02Apr2012
with the .XLS as the file extension. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need

```
OUTFILE="C:\Documents and settings\Documents\myFile &RepDate..XLS"
```

You need to use an extra . after the `&RepDate` macro variable reference. The first . terminates the macro variable reference, and the second . is then part of the string.

To understand why the . is necessary, you might want to build a filename

```
02Apr2012MyFile.XLS
```

In this case you would want to try and write:

```
&RepDateMyFile.XLS
```

but the sas interpreter wouldn't know where the macro variable names ends and the string text continues, so a dot is required in order to end the macro variable reference:

```
&RepDate.MyFile.XLS
```

In your case you want to then put a . immediately after the resolved macro variable, hence the need for two dots.

Comment: Thanks for the help. You Exactly answered the question. I had thought it would be an escape character of some type or other.